# equivalent of -e within a bash function

Tags: bash, shell

Is there an equivalent of `-e` that works inside bash functions, and returns instead of exiting?  Here is an example:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

set -e

function test1() {
  echo A
  ls alskdfal
  echo B
}

test1 || echo C
```

Right now I get the following output

```
A
ls: cannot access 'alskdfal': No such file or directory
B
```

It continues past that error even thought I have set `-e`.  I am looking for a way to get the following, without puttin `| return 1` after each line.

```
A
ls: cannot access 'alskdfal': No such file or directory
C
```

Comment: See the exercises in [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises). `set -e`'s behavior is much more contextually-dependent (and prone to variation between shell versions) than you may realize -- relying on it is an easy way to get bugs you wouldn't have if you'd written error-handling code by hand.